# How to join 2 DataFrames in pyspark sql python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 dataframes in pyspark sql

d1

```
id   features   result1
1    abc        0
3    def        1
```

d2

```
id   features   result2
1    abc        2
3    def        2
```

I want to join the dataframes like so

```
id   features   result1   result2
1    abc        0         2
3    def        1         2
```

Basically all I want to do is append df1 with the result2 column, as the id and features columns have the same values.
I have tried union, unionall and join but they have not worked.

```
new_df = UnionAll(df1,df2)
new_df = Union(df1,df2)
new_df = df1.join(df2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
joined_df = df1.join(df2, col("df1.features") == col("df2.features"), 'inner')
```